# Adding annotations to MKMapview - found nil error

Tags: swift, xcode, android-mapview

ok, I'm getting a bit frustrated with this.

I have a ViewController, which has two containers controlled by a segment controller.  One is for a table view of data, the other is for a map view of data.

The tableview loads perfectly.  The data is stored on a Firebase DB, and I have a struct set up that reads the Firebase DB, and the relevant cell code to populate the table.

My problem is with the MapView.  I am trying to set up the view so that it reads the data from the Struct and populates the map with various pins to show the location of each item.  All items in the data have lat and long coords.

When I run the app, It fails with unexpectedly found nil error,

The code of my mapView container is:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit



class TrackMapView: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var tr: newTracks!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate = self

    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tr.lat,tr.lon)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate,addressDictionary:nil))
    mapItem.name = tr.name


}

}
```

newTracks is my struct.

Can somebody help me build the code that allows me to get the data from the struct and place the pins on the map.  I am finding mapView code a bit frustrating.

my TableView container is as follows and has a number of functions to pull the data.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import FirebaseDatabase
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class TrackTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var TR: newTracks!
var track = [newTracks]()
var items: [newTracks] = []
var filteredTrack = [newTracks]()
var inSearchMode = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

    getTrackData()


}
func getTrackData() {

    let result = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "tracks")
    result.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var newItems: [newTracks] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let trackDetails = newTracks(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(trackDetails)
        }
        self.items = newItems
        self.items.sort(by: {$0.distance < $1.distance})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if inSearchMode {
        return filteredTrack.count
    } else {
        return items.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrackCell", for: indexPath) as? TrackCell {

        let tr: newTracks!
        if inSearchMode {
            tr = filteredTrack[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(track: tr)
        } else {
            tr = items[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(track: tr)
        }
        cell.configureCell(track: tr)

        cell.completion = {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tr.lat,tr.lon)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate,addressDictionary:nil))
            mapItem.name = tr.name
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey :MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
            return()
        }

        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }



}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        let lower = searchBar.text!
        filteredTrack =  items.filter({$0.name.range(of: lower) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
}
```

my storyboard, the top container works as a table view, the bottom one just displays an empty map, I need to get it showing the same data that is on the table view, but as pins on the map.

[image]

Comment: Is it `tr` that is producing the nil error? When your tableView cell is tapped, how are you populating the `tr` variable in `TrackMapView`?

Comment: yes, its tr that is producing the error, newTracks is the struct that contains all of the fields of information about each object.  what I am struggling with is how to populate tr with the relevant info.  

newTracks contains the variables name, lat and lon, so I assumed that having my variable as a type newTracks, and called tr.name, tr.lat and tr.lon it would be populated.  obviously this is not the case and I'm not sure where to call the lat, lon and name from with populated data

Comment: No, the `var tr: newTracks!` in `TrackMapView` is a brand new (empty) variable that you need to populate when the viewController is instantiated. Add a `prepare for segue` method to `TrackTableView` and access the `tr` variable in TrackMapView.

Comment: @Magnas ok, so this is starting to make sense to me now, so thank you for that :)

However what I dont understand, there is no segue between TrackTableView and TrackMapView so do I need to give the segue from ViewController to TrackMapView an identifier, then put the prepare for segue method inside TrackTableView using the identifier given?   or do I need to put the prepare for segue method inside ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to resolve this by rethinking my MapViewController.  I added the following code, and it works perfectly now.

```
 func getTrackData() {

    let result = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "tracks")
    result.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let objects = newTracks (snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            let lat = objects.lat
            let lon = objects.lon
            let name = objects.name
            let annotation = mapPoint(title: name!, locationName: name!, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!))
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation as MKAnnotation)
        }
    })
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let location = view.annotation as! mapPoint
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    location.mapItem().openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
}
```